# How can I use a TextBox Value as an argument for a ping cmd

Tags: c#, ping

I can get the ping to work, I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the value of a text box as an argument so I can ping the value from the text box. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Process test = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = "ping";
test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
test.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com";
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
test.Start();
textBox1.Text = test.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `test.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com";` to `test.StartInfo.Arguments = textBox1.Text;`, assuming that textBox1 is the text box you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, I'll give this a try!